# Find time complexity of a given nested loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, tilde

What is the time complexity for this loop below?

```
int sum = 0;
for(int n = N; n > 0; n/=2)
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum++
```

I figured out that the inner loop runs `N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ... + 1` times, but now I don't know how to proceed. How do I get the tilde or big-O from this loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1 = 2*N

Comment: Why is it equal to 2*N?

Comment: If the answer is 2*N, then tilde is 2N and big O is N, but I wonder how you got it to 2*N

Comment: @belismau: try with, say, N=16 and you will understand.

Comment: I'm not going to prove it to you, but the intuition is quite simple. You start with N, and the difference to 2N is N. You add N/2, and the difference shrinks to N/2, you add N/4, it shrinks to N/4, and so on. As you add more terms, the difference to 2N shrinks accordingly, getting smaller and smaller but never quite reaching 2N.

Comment: Aha, so if N = 16, it will run 16+8+4+2+1=31, which is nearly 2N?

Comment: @belismau it is not 2N. It is a GP series

Comment: what is GP? @Ava

Comment: Geometric Progression

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer: The sum of 1, 2, ... 2^n is 2^(n+1)-1, not 2^(n+1), and analogeously the sum of your series is not 2N but 2N-1, but for the analysis this does not matter.

Comment: @tobias_k it's (2^n - 1)

Comment: @Ava Pretty sure 1+2+4+... **+2^n** is a bit more than 2^n-1

Comment: And of course that's only if N in OP's loop is a power of two; otherwise, it may end up with considerably less than 2N or 2N-1 due to floor-division of odd numbers, but _never more_.

Comment: @belismau the time complexity O(2^n)? Did you get it or still want me to explain?

Comment: I don't get it. Please explain again. Isn't it O(2N)?

Comment: @belismau Yes, it is `O(2N) = O(N) ` (in complexity theory constant factors are omitted)

Answer (score 0):

Big-O from this loop is O(N) such as the dependence of the number of iterations on N is linear.

About 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

About Big-O https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation

Comment: That is the sum of infinite GP series.

Answer (score 0):

N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ... + 1 forms a GP(geometric progress) which sums up to 2N. While defining time complexity in terms of big O, we discard the constant. So time complexity of your problem is O(N).

Comment: How do you get ***N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ... + 1*** to 2N?

Comment: First time outer loop's 'n' value is N so inner loop will run N times, next time it is divided by half bcoz of n/=2 so inner loop will run N/2 times, next time inner loop will run N/4 times and so on...